# Python 3 Pexpect - spawnu issue: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 273: invalid start byte

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, python-3.3, pexpect

I'm having an issue when using spawnu (UTF-8) from the Pexpect module for Python 3 during a SSH session when the remote machine responds with the following characters in the output:

```
ÿÿÿÿ
```

Here's the error the I received:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 273: invalid start byte
```

When I throw an `interact()` in before I receive the input, everything comes through okay, which is why I believe the issue is with spawnu.

I'm looking for workarounds or alternative methods.

Answer (score 2):

add `codec_errors='ignore'` after encoding

something like:

```
proc = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=timeout, maxread=maxread, logfile=context.log, encoding='utf-8', codec_errors='ignore')
```